# React canvas in css grid not full size

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, canvas

I am building a line plotter in react. This "line plotter" should be inside a css grid in an item.
To plot the lines I am trying to use the `<canvas>` element. First of all is that smart or are there better ways?
But secondly and most importantly my canvas is not set to the full size inside the grid item. Is there any way of doing that and later also setting the origin of the canvas into the middle of the canvas?
My code so far:

```
const Canvas = props => {

    const { draw, settings, ...rest } = props
    const canvasRef = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {

        const canvas = canvasRef.current
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
        draw(context, settings)
    }, [draw])

    return (
        <div className={"fractal_tree_canvas"}>
            <canvas ref={canvasRef}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and the css

```
.fractal_tree_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;

}
```

And finally the gird:

```
.fractal_tree_screen {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  display: inline-grid;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vh - 65px);
  grid-template-columns: 5% 50% auto 5%;
  grid-template-rows: 6% 1fr 6%;

}
```

But somehow my canvas end up having the size 300x150 waht could I do to make it the full size of the item?

Comment: have you tried add this class: `canvas{width: 100%; height: 100%}` ?

Comment: yes but this simple changes the size of the canvas and not the resolution or the origin position and for instance `ctx.canvas.width` is still the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<canvas` is not designed to be responsive or controlled by CSS like other elements.
To control its  width and height you have to set its [width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/width) and [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/height) HTML attributes.

If these attributes are not set, it'll default to `300x150` which is happening in your case.

Since you have React, you can calculate the desired values and set it in JSX itself.

If you want to handle resize, you need to listen to resize event, change canvas attributes accordingly and redraw it.

Comment: okay, thank you very much is there a similar thing like canvas but able to work with css?

Comment: @SebNik it depends on what you want, for things like chart, look at `<svg>`